# Can malloc failure cause deadlock or cause race-condition?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, malloc, deadlock

Taken from a text book:

> One small tricky issue arises if malloc() happens to fail (a rare case);  in this case, the code must also release the lock before failing the insert.

Example Given:

```
int List_Insert(list_t *L, int key) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&L->lock);
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
       perror("malloc");
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
       return -1; // fail
    }
    new->key  = key;
    new->next = L->head;
    L->head   = new;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
    return 0; // success
}
```

This will work.(Consider everything else is perfect)

**If I write as below**, will it cause deadlock? Can multiple threads access shared memory(Race condition)? I am trying to understand what really happens when malloc fails in a thread which has acquired a lock. I don't want a correct solution, I want to know the explanation/end result of malloc failure in a thread having acquired lock. Assume all other functions are implemented correctly.

```
int List_Insert(list_t *L, int key) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&L->lock);
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new->key  = key;
    new->next = L->head;
    L->head   = new;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
    return 0; // success
}
```

Comment: What do you think happens when `malloc` fails and you execute `new->key = key;`?

Answer (score 1):

If malloc fails and returns NULL the behavior of your second function is undefined. And it's as big of a concern as a deadlock if not more.

The very likely effect of this is that your program will seg fault (you are, it appears, on one of the Unices).  If you installed a `SIGSEGV` handler for whatever reason, then it will deadlock, since execution shouldn't return from a `SIGSEGV` handler (again risking undefined behavior if it does).

If you didn't install a handler, then the program will simply crash and possibly leave a core dump. So on the whole, your program is in a pretty much irrecoverable state. The deadlock between threads will last only for as long as it takes to crash.

If failure to allocate *is not* an immediately irrecoverable state for your program, you should definitely go with the first function. And if it is, I suggest you just abort explicitly rather then leave a bunch of undefined behavior in your code.

Answer (score 1):

A `malloc()` failure has no direct effect on locking, data races, *etc*..  Your text is in fact not calling out `malloc()` failure as a special case; that's just the failure mode possible in the code it's discussing.

The point is that having once acquired the mutex, a thread must be certain to release it, even in the event of a failure of any kind.  If it does not do so then no other thread will thereafter be able to acquire the mutex; this *could* produce a deadlock, but whether it in fact does so depends on many other factors.

Thus, the textbook is discriminating between its good example and this BAD alternative:

```
int List_Insert(list_t *L, int key) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&L->lock);
    node_t *new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
       perror("malloc");
       // BAD BAD BAD: function exits without unlocking the mutex!!!
       return -1; // fail
    }
    // ...
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&L->lock);
    return 0; // success
}
```

It goes without saying (but I'll say anyway) that if `malloc()` fails, as indicated by returning `NULL`, it does not provide any memory you can use.  It is a problem of an altogether different kind to neglect checking for `malloc()` failure at all.